# PhpStorm is not showing correctly my node_modules

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have problem with PhpStorm (WebStorm) and `node_modules`. Very often IDE is not aware of some libraries.

Now `node_modules` is not excluded and I think it should. But `node_modules` is not added to javascript/libraries and I don't know how to do it.

Here is my project screenshots:

[image]
[image]

And this is my other project which works well.

[image]
[image]

How to fix it??

Comment: what IDE version do you use? In current version (2018.1.x), there are 2 ways to make this library disappear: 1) exclude/unexclude `node_modules` dir manually 2) remove the `package.json` from its parent dir. In the first case, deleting `.idea` folder should help to get the library back. In the latter case, you need to make sure to add appropriate `package.json` file

Comment: Thanks for comment. deleting .idea folder didn't help. I started new project and create `package.json` and installed it using IDE command. `node_modules` folder is not excluded and not added in `libraries` setting. So how it is with `node_modules` folder? Should it be excluded or not?

Comment: it should be auto-excluded, and direct dependencies listed in package.json should be added to javaScript libraries. `node_modules` folder should then be marked as *library root*

Comment: Than something is wrong :/ I PhpStorm have 2018.1.5

Comment: can you share a project that can be used to recreate the issue?

Comment: I posted it also on WebStorm forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000017859-node-modules-not-excluded

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by PHP settings - `node_modules` is not treated as a library root if project directory is added to PHP include paths.  To work out the issue, please remove `.` from PHP include paths in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP, Include Path** and re-open the project.

Issue is tracked as [WEB-33211](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33211), please follow it for updates